# не получается настроить Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Мой код:

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram import Sticker
from telegram import Update
from telegram import KeyboardButton
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.utils.request import Request


def do_start(bot: Bot):     
    text = "Привет! Отправь мне что-нибудь"
    bot.send_message(update.message.chat_id, text)


def main():

    req = Request(
        connect_timeout=0.5,
    )
    bot = Bot(
        request=req,
        token=TOKEN,
        base_url='https://telegg.ru/orig/bot',
    )
    updater = Updater(
        bot=bot,
        use_context=True,
    )

    # Обработчики команд
    start_handler = CommandHandler("start", do_start)
    message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, do_echo)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler) 
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Но при отправке боту `/start` ничего не происходит

**И каким образом я могу отправлять пользователю стикер?**

Comment: А почему не воспользоваться примерами библиотеки, и не настроить под себя?

Comment: При запуске бота, должна была появиться ошибка про отсутствие `do_echo`

Answer (score 0):

1. Во-первых вам необходимо добавить хендлеры(декораторы) в ваш код. Прочитать про них можно [здесь](https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/extra/pytelegrambotapi_basics).
2. Во-вторых в конце кода необходимо добавить строку `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`.
3. В-третьих вам нужно указать значение unicode для emoji. Читать рекомендую [тут](https://github.com/mustafababil/Telegram-Weather-Bot/blob/master/responseController.py#L11).